# como guardar en una variable el valor de otra variable que obtiene su valor del e.target y que no se vuelva a actualizar otra vez

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, dom, ecmascript-6

```
        function deleteProduct(e) {
    let idProducto = 
        Number(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
        return idProducto;
   }
```

tengo esta función que me retorna un id de una fila de una tabla. que luego voy a usar en una funcion que se activa al clicar un boton fuera de la tabla para borrar ese elemento. pero no me reconoce desde esa funcion el id.

```
function applyActionDelete() {
    let arrayItems = getLS();
    arrayItems.slice(deleteProduct(), 1);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arrayItems));
    window.location.href = 'store.html';
}
```

[image: la primera funcion se ejecuta al precionar cualquier fila de la tabla, la segunda funcion se ejecuta al darle click al boton de la barra de navegación que tiene una imagen de un cesto de basura]

la primera funcion se ejecuta al precionar cualquier fila de la tabla, la segunda funcion se ejecuta al darle click al boton de la barra de navegación que tiene una imagen de un cesto de basura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma que intentas es incorrecta porque cuando llamas a la primera funcion desde la segunda no estas pasando ningun evento, por lo que la primera funcion va a retornar null.  Tienes dos opciones, usar un campo escondido `<input type="hidden">` o una variable global.  Lo mas facil es una variable global asi:

```
function deleteProduct(e) {
    idProducto = Number(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);        
}
function applyActionDelete() {
    let arrayItems = getLS();
    arrayItems.slice(idProducto, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(arrayItems));
    window.location.href = 'store.html';
}
```